# Gridview row delete/remove when paging is enabled

Tags: c#, gridview, paging, aspxgridview

I am having a gridview with paging enabled.

When I try to delete a row on a page other than page 1 it is deleting the incorrect row and not the row for which the delete button is pressed.

```
protected void GVRequest_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[index].Delete();

        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

        DataView view = new DataView(dtCurrentTable);
        DataTable dt1 = view.ToTable(true, "CartonID", "FileID", "FileMasterID", "DeptFileID", "RequestID");

        GVRequest.DataSource = dt1;

        DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Replace Your

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[index].Delete();
```

with

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[index-1].Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
protected void GVRequest_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
        int p = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Pageindex"]);
        int s = GVRequest.PageSize;
        p = p * s;
        DataTable dtCurrentTable= new DataTable();
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
        int dl = d + p;
        dt = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[dl].Delete();

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

    DataView view = new DataView(dtCurrentTable);
    DataTable dt1 = view.ToTable(true, "CartonID", "FileID", "FileMasterID", "DeptFileID", "RequestID");

    GVRequest.DataSource = dt1;

    DataBind();
        ViewState["Pageindex"] = 0;
}

protected void NextPage(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GVRequest.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    ViewState["Pageindex"] = e.NewPageIndex;
    GVRequest.DataSource = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable; //get datasource (list or datatable)
    DataBind();
}
```

You don't want to assume anything if you use above code